# Ad-hoc Wi-fi disconnects as soon as I rdc into a Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, ad-hoc-network

So, I have two notebooks: one is Windows 7 Enterprise lets call it "E" - other is Windows 7 Home Premium - lets call it "H".

I have a 3G USB dongle which connects me to internet. The goal is to connect both computers to the internet and I should be able to use computer "E" from computer "H". I have stationed "E" and I can move around with "H" - reason is that you cannot remote desktop to Home Premium. So, only way is to RDC from "H" to "E".

I create Windows Ad-hoc network on "E" - and share my USB wireless connection on that network - make "H" join the network - everything works fine. Only problem is I have to physically go to "E" when I want to connect/disconnect the USB device. Hence, I want to do it other way round. Carry USB device with me along with "H".

So, I create Ad-hoc network from "H" this time and share USB internet connection on it - make "E" join the network. However, as soon as I try to RDC into "E", it disconnects from the ad-hoc network. 
While attempting to RDC, it prompts for user/passwd, and also shows "Welcome" screen - after that RDC window goes black - as the remote machine "E" has disconnected from Wi-fi.

This happens every-time and its not intermittent. How can solve this problem?

Comment: No other way for me other than heading over to E's console. Wi-fi network is listed - but its not connected anymore. I checked event logs - nothing in Application. However, in System, it looks like the machine is trying to contact domain controller - oh, yeah, forgot to mention E belongs to a domain - and domain controller is not available here. Could this be related? If so, then why isnt this an issue when I start ad-hoc network from E?